# Bootstrap 5 carousel stuck on first image

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to include a carousel in my html page, but it only shows the first image and even though the next and previous text appears I'm unable to navigate. I literally copy and pasted the code from bootstrap.

```
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/styles.css" />

              <div class="col project-images">
                <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                  </ol>
                  <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                      <img class="d-block w-100" src="../static/personal_website/code.png" alt="First slide">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                      <img class="d-block w-100" src="../static/personal_website/landing_page.png" alt="Second slide">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                  </a>
                  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I managed to get the carousel to start moving by changing "data-ride" to "data-bs-ride" since apparently that's a change with bootstrap 5, but I still can't get the previous and next buttons to do anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="carousel-indicators">
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
  </div>
```